# Predict an algorithm's theoretical average-case efficiency and order of growth using summation

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I need to predict the algorithm's average case efficiency with respect to the size of its inputs using summation/sigma notation to arrive at the final answer. Many resources use summation to predict worst-case, and I couldn't find someone explaining how to predict average case so step-by-step answers are appreciated.

The algorithm contains a nested for loop, with the basic operation inside the innermost loop:

[code redacted]

**EDIT:** The execution of the basic operation it will always execute inside the second for loop if the second for loop has been entered, and has no break or return statements. HOWEVER: the end of the first for loop has the return statement which is dependent on the value produced in the basic operation, so the contents of the array do affect how many total times the basic operation will be executed for each run of the algorithm.

**The array passed to the algorithm has randomly generated contents**

I think the predicted average case efficiency is (n^2)/2, making it n^2 order of growth/big Theta of n^2, but I don't know how to theoretically prove this using summation.
Answers are very appreciated!

Comment: As you don't seems to have break/return in basic operation, you do all the loop always, so `O(n²)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I believe that they are asking how to represent this in summation notation

Comment: Yes, it would fall under O(n^2) but I'm asking how to find the equation for average case efficiency that would then yield bigTheta.

Comment: @user7804781 Feel free for any queries.

Comment: @user7804781 Hope now it is clear.

Comment: "randomly generated contents" isn't enough -- usually analysis of this sort of algorithm uses "uniformly random permutation of 1..N", but here your code handles repeated numbers, so presumably the distribution of inputs includes repeated values. But then the exact details matter -- for example if each element is chosen randomly from a finite set of size K (with replacement) the average case will be something like O(NK). If the elements are chosen from an infinite distribution, then the result will be something else depending on the distribution.

Comment: @Paul Hankin the values are randomly chosen from 0 to a maximum value which can be changed for each run. There can be multiple elements with the same value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Your code complexity in average case is `Θ(n²)` if "basic operation" complexity is `Θ(1)` and it has no `return`, `break` or `goto` operators.

**Explanation:** the average-case complexity is just an expectation of the number of operations in your code given the size of the input.

Let's say `T(A, n)` is a number of operations your code performs given array `A` of size `n`. It's easy to see that

```
T(A, n) = 1  +                // int k = ceil(size/2.0);
    n * 2 + 1 +               // for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    n * (n * 2 + 1) +         // for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
    n * n * X +               // //Basic operation 
    1                         // return (some int);
```

Where `X` is a number of operations in your "basic operation". As we can see, `T(A, n)` does not depend on actual contents of the array `A`. Thus, the expected number of operations given size of the array (which is simply the arithmetical mean of `T(A, n)` for all possible `A` for given `n`) is exactly equal to each of them:

```
T(n) = T(A, n) = 3 + n * 2 + n * n * (2 + X)
```

If we assume that `X = Θ(1)`, this expression is `Θ(n²)`.

Even without this assumption we can have an estimate: if `X = Θ(f(n))`, then your code complexity is `T(n) = Θ(f(n)n²)`. For example, if `X` is `Θ(log n)`, `T(n) = Θ(n² log n)`

Comment: How do you get `n * 2 + 1` from `// for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`?

Comment: Do you know how to show the predicted average case complexity of this algorithm using summation/sigma notation? Using sigma notation, I need to arrive at an equation that would be the step before eliminating constants and give the bigTheta(n^2), i.e. use summation notation to arrive at the average case complexity of (n^2)/2

Comment: @user7804781 For the average , best case  and worst case you would have the same equation. Usually for the average case, equations involve probabilities, when the code is undeterministic.

Comment: @user7804781 But your code does not have any randomized part, therefore no need for probabilities and hence the simple equation.

Comment: I realized I forgot to add in the last if statement for the return. Please see the corrected code, my apologies.

Comment: @bpgeck 1 operation for `int i = 0`, `n` operations for `i < size` and `n` operations for `i++`.